# Are the gcc memory hooks sometimes bypassed?

Tags: c, memory, gcc, hook

For a c++ arm application I need to trace the memory allocations. To this I am using the gcc memory hooks. For now I am printing the allocations and deallocations, see code below.

However, the `malloc`'s and `free`'s don't add up. Sometimes I see a `free` on a memory block that pass through didn't the malloc hook before. Or memory is freed twice. Of course this could be a bug in my code,although I don't get a segfault. But I also see that `malloc` sometimes returns a pointer that it has returned before and there has been no `free` in meantime (at least my free hook wasn't called).

So my guess is that certain `malloc`'s and `free'`s are not passed through my hooks. Note that when I only trace the c++ allocations then things do add up nicely.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <new>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

static void push_memhooks();
static void pop_memhooks();

static void *malloc_hook(size_t size, const void *ret)
{

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    pop_memhooks();

    void *mem = malloc(size);

    if (mem) {
        printf("malloc %p\n", mem);
    }

    push_memhooks();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return mem;
}

static void *realloc_hook(void* ptr, size_t size, const void *ret)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    pop_memhooks();

    void* mem = realloc(ptr, size);

    if (mem) {
        printf("realloc %p -> %p\n", ptr, mem);
    }

    push_memhooks();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return mem;
}

static void* memalign_hook(size_t boundary, size_t size, const void *ret)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pop_memhooks();

    void* mem = memalign(boundary, size);

    if (mem) {
        printf("memalign %p\n", mem);
    }

    push_memhooks();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return mem;
}

static void free_hook(void *mem, const void *ret)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    pop_memhooks();

    free(mem);

    printf("free %p\n", mem);

    push_memhooks();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    void* mem = malloc(size);

    if (!mem) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    return mem;
}

void operator delete(void* mem)
{
    free(mem);
}

void *operator new[](size_t size)
{       
    void* mem = malloc(size);

    if (!mem) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    return mem;
}

void operator delete[](void* mem)
{
    free(mem);
}

static int memhooks = 0;

static void push_memhooks()
{
    if (++memhooks == 1) {
        __malloc_hook = malloc_hook;
        __realloc_hook = realloc_hook;
        __free_hook = free_hook;
        __memalign_hook = memalign_hook;
    }
}

static void pop_memhooks()
{
    if (--memhooks == 0) {
        __malloc_hook = NULL;
        __realloc_hook = NULL;
        __free_hook = NULL;
        __memalign_hook = NULL;
    }
}

static void install_memhooks ()
{
    push_memhooks();
}

void (*__malloc_initialize_hook)(void) = install_memhooks;
```

For example, I get the following output when I grep the trace for a pointer which shows the strange behaviour.

```
<snip>
malloc 0x8234818
free 0x8234818
malloc 0x8234818
malloc 0x8234818
free 0x8234818
<snip>
```

Notice the two consecutive malloc's.

**Solution**: As Chris mentioned in his answer, there's a race condition in the code above. Unfortunately, the malloc hooks cannot be safely used in a multithreaded environment when removing and reinstalling the hooks the way I do. For the same reason, mcheck cannot be used in multithreaded apps (http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9939).

Implementing `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` and calling the libc versions using `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc")` didn't work either. First, `dlsym` calls `calloc`, so special care is needed to prevent infinite recursion here. Second, when calling the libc `malloc`, the process hangs. Furthermore, I see that my `__malloc_initialize_hook` doesn't get called. So I guess that by providing my own `malloc` implementation, the libc `malloc` isn't properly initialized.

My current solution has the dlmalloc implementation embedded to remove the dependency on the libc malloc. Now I don't have to continuously remove/reinstall the malloc hooks. I install the hooks once and my hooks allocate memory using dlmalloc.

Comment: Are you perhaps calling fork()?  That might explain two consecutive mallocs with the same address.  A call to fork() would create a separate process that would have its own address space.  This, however, would not explain a free without a preceding malloc (assuming no bugs in the code).

Comment: Could you add a `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` calls? I also don't exactly understand why you pop and push your memory hooks all the time...

Comment: @sharth I need to remove the hooks temporarily to avoid recursion. In the hook functions I call the memory operation again. See the example code at http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: Oh. That makes a ton of sense. Perhaps to help you get the dlopen version going, I had previously written one for malloc. Maybe it will help. https://gist.github.com/701897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in a multithreaded environment, you have a race condition that might cause you to miss calls to malloc/free.  When your malloc_hook function is called, it unhooks all the hooks, calls malloc and then rehooks the hooks.  If some other thread calls malloc/free while the hooks are unhooked, you won't see that call.  Your mutex doesn't help, as while unhooked, a malloc/free call won't call your hook function, so won't wait on the mutex.

**edit**

My preferred way of hooking/intecepting malloc in a program is to just intercept the calls from my program by using macros, without worrying about calls from within the stdlib.  Create a wrap_malloc file with:

```
#define malloc(sz)     wrap_malloc(sz, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define free(p)        wrap_free(p, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define realloc(p, sz) wrap_realloc(p, sz, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define calloc(s1, s2) wrap_calloc(s1, s2, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

then compile all my code with `-imacros wrap_malloc`.  The file that defines wrap_malloc and friends just needs the appropriate `#undef`s, but no other changes to the code are needed.

Comment: Aaah, good catch! So I guess I can't do this with the malloc hooks. I will have to implement malloc and friends and use some dlopen magic to get a function pointer to the libc functions. Right?

Comment: One of the reasons that we are tracing memory is because we are also interested in the memory usage of some 3rd party libraries. I cannot trace memory in libraries using your macros (without recompiling the libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to what extend you control this code and how you try to detect if `malloc/free` match up. But one thing that may happen is that either of them is disguised as `realloc`. This one can with certain types of arguments have the same effect as a `malloc` (initial pointer is 0) or as `free` (new size is 0), IIRC.

**Edit:** I see that you are using pthreads? Another possibility is that your `malloc/free` happen in order, but your `printf` for your debug output get out of order. Access to the `FILE*` variables is usually mutexed. Try to prefix your debug output with a timestamp and first sort according to that time stamp.

Comment: I have written both pieces of code myself, so I am free to change them. Both cases of realloc you mention are handled correctly. Besides, I also see mismatches on non realloc'ed memory. See my updated question.